# recuperar evento jquery

Tags: jquery, eventos

Uso la libreria `jquery.mobile-events.min`, para controlar los eventos swipe en moviles.

En determinado momento me interesa detener la función deslizamiento.

```
$(function(){$('#touch-zone').on('swipeleft', function(e) { alert('izq'); })
});
$(document).ready(function(){

        $('#borrar').click(function() {alert();
                        $('#touch-zone').off('tap');            
                                    })
                    $('#volver').click(function() {alert('volver');
                        $('#touch-zone').trigger('tap');                
                                    })

                                })

    Todo va bien, al pulsar "borrar" se anulala el evento swipeleft, sin embargo triger no va, al pulsar "volver" no me recupera el evento.
```

Podeís ayudarme
Saludos cordiales

Comment: Supongo que te refieres a esta: https://github.com/pao/jQuery-Mobile-Events si es le caso, desafortunadamente yo no tengo acceso a github en este momento

Comment: Si quieres puedo envite el js.

Comment: Buenas Angel. Parece que has creado otra cuenta. Mira este enlace para pedir que las fusionen: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3430/vincular-a-mi-cuenta-de-usuario-una-pregunta-que-hice-como-invitado/3431#3431